# ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression" *Cause:

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

create table programer(IDNO NUMBER, PROJECTID VARCHAR(5),LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),HIRINGDATE DATE('YYYY-MM-DD') ,LANGUAGES VARCHAR(15),TASKNO INT,Privileges VARCHAR(25));

desc programer;
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(201,'NPR','GUPTA','SAURAV',to_date('01-05-95', 'mm-dd-yy'),'VB',52,'SECRET');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(390,'KCW','GHOSH','PINKY',to_date('01-05-93', 'mm-dd-yy'),'JAVA',11,'TOPSECRET');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(789,'RNC','AGARWAL','PRAVEEN',to_date('08-03-98', 'mm-dd-yy'),'VB',11,'SECRET');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(134,'TIPPS','CHAUDHURY','SUPRIYO',to_date('07-15-95', 'mm-dd-yy'),'C++',52,'SECRET');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(896,'KCW','GJHA','RANJIT',to_date('06-15-97', 'mm-dd-yy'),'JAVA',10,'TOPSECRET');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(345,'TIPPS','JOHN','PETER',to_date('11-15-99', 'mm-dd-yy'),'JAVA',52,'');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(563,'NITTS','ANDERSON','ANDY',to_date('08-15-94', 'mm-dd-yy'),'C++',89,'CONFIDENTIAL');

SELECT IDNO, PROJECTID,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,HIRINGDATE,LANGUAGES,TASKNO ,Privileges FROM PROGRAMER;
```

Comment: At which line is the error generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DATE` data type does not take any parameters. You need to change the delcaration `HIRINGDATE  DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')`  to

```
HIRINGDATE  DATE,
```

A `DATE` value is not stored with any format, so trying to specify one does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your CREATE TABLE statement needs correction as below:

```
create table programer(IDNO NUMBER, PROJECTID VARCHAR(5),LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),HIRINGDATE DATE ,LANGUAGES VARCHAR(15),TASKNO INT,Privileges VARCHAR(25));
```

Comment: privileges is also a key word

Answer (score 0):

create table programer1 (IDNO NUMBER, PROJECTID VARCHAR(5),LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),HIRINGDATE DATE ,LANGUAGES VARCHAR(15),TASKNO INT,Privileges1 VARCHAR(25));
desc programer1;